# Terminal Mac 10.5.8 Command not found

Tags: macos, terminal, command

I have Mac 10.5.8. I must have done something wrong with the PATH while downloading Android SDK. When I type any command in the terminal, it shows that "Command not found". I tried the following command:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

This line solved my problem temporarily. As soon as I quit the Terminal and re open it, it shows the following line:

```
-bash: export: `2/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools': not a valid identifier
```

The above solution is temporary. Could anyone please give me some clear and simple steps how to solve this problem permanently? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Could you please add the contents of ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_login?

Comment: I have used the following commands to see the contents of bash_login: touch .bash_login
open .bash_login  The file is empty. Any idea?

Comment: open the terminal, fix your path temporarily (using the same approach as before), type "ls -ad .b*" to see all files whose names start with .b, type "cat .bashrc | pbpaste" to copy the contents of .bashrc to your clipboard. Repeat for .bash_profile.

Comment: If .bash_login is empty, that's fine; at least, you can be sure it doesn't contain any wrong settings.

Comment: It is telling me this message: cat: .bashrc: No such file or directory
  Any idea?

Comment: Yes, it is empty. Based on my commands I have sent to open the bash_login. What should I do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you followed the instructions from [Talkandroid installation guide](http://www.talkandroid.com/guides/developer/android-sdk-install-guide/) or similar. Then, you probably edited ~/.bash_profile (*not* ~/.bash_login) and entered something like:

```
export PATH=$SDK_ROOT/tools
```

Replace this line with

```
export PATH=$PATH;$SDK_ROOT/tools
```

and restart your shell and you should be fine.

**UPDATE:**

If your current line is

```
export PATH=$:/Users/refai/Applications/eclipse 2/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools
```

you forgot the PATH after the $; replacing this with

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/refai/Applications/eclipse 2/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools
```

should fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for this. I had been working on this for a very time. I have deleted the whole line for Android to make sure I would solve the terminal problem. I have added the following line for SDK: export PATH=$:/Users/refai/Applications/eclipse 2/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools  I would be extremely grateful if you could possibly guide me how to re modify this line with the one you have sent me. Your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: I have added your update to the .bash_login file. I closed and re opened the Terminal and do not have the problem anymore. I opened Eclipse and found the following message:

[2013-10-16 13:53:36 - Android SDK] Error when loading the SDK:

Error: Missing platform-tools [2013-10-16 13:54:21 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]

Error: Expected verb after global parameters but found 'sdk' instead'

Do you think the problem is still with the path? I think the SDK Manager is not there. How can I do? Could you please guide me what to do at the point? Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've never installed the Android SDK. I'd suggest you post a separate question on StackOverflow for this.